# Censoring words found in STDIN and printing to STDOUT not working

Tags: c, arrays, printing, c-strings

My program is supposed to take any number of one-word text string arguments, each less than 128 characters long. It copies any text from stdin to stdout, except that any of the words seen in the input are replaced with the word CENSORED. So far it kinda works. Any ideas on how I can fix it?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
char word[128];
int index = 0;
int c = getchar();

while (c != EOF){
    //checks for letter and adds to word[]
    if ((c>='A' && c<='Z') || (c>='a' && c<='z') || c == '\''){
        word[index] = (char)c;
        index++;
        word[index] = '\0';
    }
    //when c is not a letter or ' (end of word)
    else{ 
        if (index > 0){
            int found;
            for (int i=1;i<argc;i++){
                //if word[] is found in input censor it
                if (strcmp(word,argv[i]) == 0){
                    printf("CENSORED");
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //prints word[] if it's not in input
            if (found != 1){
                printf("%s",word);
            }

        }
        //resets word[] and index / prints value of c
        word[0] = '\0';
        index = 0;
        printf("%c",(char)c);
    }
    //increment c
    c = getchar();
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You said it works, what kind of fix do you need? Please edit your qurstion and describe the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems.  First, you should not be overflowing your buffer if you do get a word >127 characters.   Change:

```
    word[index] = (char)c;
    index++;
```

to:

```
    if ( index+1 < sizeof(word) ) {
        word[index] = (char)c;
        index++;
    }
```

The other problem, likely the one you have noticed, is that you aren't initializing `found`.  Make it:

```
        int found = 0;
```